# Gerar erro 403 php

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-403

Olá, tenho uma página em php onde eu queria que quando o utilizador não estivesse logado gerasse um erro 403 e apresentasse uma página de padrão no apache.
A página padrão do erro 403 está a funcionar, só queria que desse erro no php tal como se eu tentasse visionar um diretório.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça comparação se o usuário está logado ou não, se não estiver defina o header para o erro na saida:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
```

Comment: Olá, mesmo assim ele não mostra a página de erro que eu defini, podia me dar outra solução?

Comment: Tenta apontar o erro e incluir uma página de erro; include '/errors/403.php', obs: crie essa pasta/pagina na raiz do seu diretório